# Unable to register domain on child account - AWS Organizations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-billing, aws-organizations

I've created a new AWS account from my already existing master account using AWS Organizations.

Now, I would like to purchase a domain using Route 53 from the new account using the credit card which is already linked to the master account. However, when I'm trying to register, it's giving me an error:

> Domain registration failed: [We can't finish registering your domain because we can't process your payment. Check your payment information and try again.]

There is no credit card linked to the new account. I would like to use the one that is already linked to the master account.

Please advise on how to use the credit card which is in the master account to register a domain in the child account. Thank you!